# Oscillator, and moving average overlay

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

how can I overlay a moving average over the candlestick chart, while an oscillator is displayed below?
Do I need to define a moving average to a variable, then create another variable with the ma variable as an input or source?
Can I use plotchar to draw the moving average variable?
Basically is it possible, and if so how do I go about it?

Pinescript version5 on trading view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your oscillator is on a separate pane, you cannot do that. You need two indicators here, one for the oscillator `overlay=false` and one for the ma `overlay=true`.